# Fetching table details according to current logged in user

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, materialize

I have two tables. NGO and Volunteer. Volunteer is selecting in which NGO it is interested to work. After NGO logs in, I want to display only those records from volunteers tables, who are interested in current logged in NGO. My code is as follows:

```
[<?php
            if(!$db){
                die("Connection Failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            else{
                echo"Success!<br>";
            }
            $current_user=$_SESSION\['login_user'\];
            echo $current_user;
            $sql1=mysqli_query($db,"select *,Name,ngo.EmailId from volunteer,ngo where ngo.EmailId='".$_SESSION\['login_user'\]."' and volunteer.OName=ngo.Name");
            $row=mysqli_num_rows($sql1);

            echo"<table><tr><th>Volunteer Name</th>
                            <th>Volunteer EmailId</th>
                            <th>BirthDate</th>
                            <th>PhoneNo</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                            <th>Volunteer Reason</th>
                        </tr>";

            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)){
                //if($result->num_rows>0){
                    //while($row=$sql->fetch_assoc()){
                    echo"<tr><td>".$row['VName']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['EmailId']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['Birthdate']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['PhoneNo']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['Gender']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['Address']."</td>
                            <td>".$row['VolReason']."</td>
                        </tr>";
            }
                //}
            echo"</table>";
        ?>
```

And here is its the output:[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gzKV.png)
It is event printing the current user but it is not comparing the $current_user with NGO column name EmailID.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your table layout is like but for the sake of this say you have an NGO table which all have an ID, then in your volunteer table you have a column that represents the NGO the volunteer chose (i just called it 'chosen_ngo'). Then your query to would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM volunteers INNER JOIN ngo ON ngo.id=volunteers.chosen_ngo WHERE ngo.email='$email_variable'
```